# how can I recover my private key from my passphrase and password

Tags: synchronization, passphrase

I decided recently to get some BTC and bitcoin core was the storage solution I decided on.

I downloaded the software, and all seemed good. No messages about storage or such.

Around a month later I purchased BTC from an atm and sent it to the Core address.

Upon returning home, I found it was "out of sync". I literally wiped everything off my 250gb Mac in order to accommodate it. Still nothing.

I attempted to reduce the cache size, however Core told me I should reset, and so I did. However, this too didn't help.

I am trying to find how I can recover my private key from my passphrase and password.

Comment: Bitcoin core does not support importing mnemonic words or a seed.

Answer (score 0):

> **I am trying to find how I can recover my private key from my passphrase and password**

In general you cannot recover a private key from a wallet password or wallet passphrase.

---

If what you are calling a ["passphrase"](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Passphrase_generation) is really a ["recovery phrase" or "seed phrase"](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Seed_phrase), then you can recover private keys from that. A recovery phrase typically consists of twelve or twenty-four words, usually generated for you by the wallet before use, usually from a specific word-list.

AFAIK current Bitcoin Core does not support recovery phrases.

---

If the wallet is still working, make a backup (`File -> Backup Wallet`) or extract the `wallet.dat` file and recreate the wallet on a machine with more capacity -- or -- [extract the *private keys*](https://github.com/OmniLayer/omniwallet/wiki/Exporting-a-private-key-from-Bitcoin-Qt---Bitcoin-Core-and-importing-to-Omniwallet.org) and import or sweep them into a wallet that supports SPV. Don't delete anything from your 250GB Mac until you have the new wallet working.